# Computing ratio between elements with dplyr in R data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Suppose we have a data frame (`df`) like this:

```
a b
1 2
2 4
3 6
```

If I want to compute the ratio of each element in vectors `a` and `b` and assign to variable `c`, we'd do this:

`c <- df$a / df$b`

However, I was wondering how the same thing could be done using the `dplyr` package? I.e. are there any ways that this can be achieved using functions from `dplyr`?

Comment: Can this help you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28487526/calculating-ratios-by-group-with-dplyr

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mutate` function from `dplyr` library:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), b= c(2,4,6))

library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
           dplyr::mutate(c = a/b)
```

Console output:

```
  a b   c
1 1 2 0.5
2 2 4 0.5
3 3 6 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the code below

```
df %>%
  mutate(c = do.call("/", .))
```

or

```
df %>%
  mutate(c = Reduce("/", .))
```

or

```
df %>%
  mutate(c = a/b)
```

Comment: What's the advantage of the first 2 options over the third one? Seems like an attempt to scale up that would actually backfire if there were indeed more columns there

Comment: @camille Yes, you can skip typing the column names when you have many

Comment: But if you have e.g. 5 columns, and you use one of those first 2 options, you're dividing all your columns and no longer calculating a ratio. That's what I mean by scaling up an operation that doesn't actually make sense to scale

Comment: @camille Yes, I got your point. Actually `do.call` and `Reduce` are applicable here is just due to the fact that the terms for manipulation is noncommutable and has just two columns. One the number of columns scales up and terms are commutable, `Reduce` would be one possible and lovely option. The reason I put the first two methods there since we can achieve the objective without know the specific column names.

Answer (score 0):

An option with `invoke`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
   mutate(c = invoke('/', .))
```

-output

```
#  a b   c
#1 1 2 0.5
#2 2 4 0.5
#3 3 6 0.5
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), b= c(2,4,6))
```